# Movement Loop in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have 4 objects each located in a corner of a square. I wish to move these objects clockwise, 1 position per method call.

With the code I have atm, they all just complete the entire loop on 1 method call instead of moving only one position...

My code so far:

```
void SwitchPositions() 
    {

            tempPosition1 = parent.transform.GetChild(0).GetComponent<Transform>().position;
            tempPosition2 = parent.transform.GetChild(1).GetComponent<Transform>().position;
            tempPosition3 = parent.transform.GetChild(2).GetComponent<Transform>().position;
            tempPosition4 = parent.transform.GetChild(3).GetComponent<Transform>().position;
            parent.transform.GetChild (0).GetComponent<Transform> ().position = tempPosition2;
            parent.transform.GetChild (1).GetComponent<Transform> ().position = tempPosition3;
            parent.transform.GetChild (2).GetComponent<Transform> ().position = tempPosition4;
            parent.transform.GetChild (3).GetComponent<Transform> ().position = tempPosition1;
            Debug.Log (tempPosition1);


    }
```

If anyone has any ideas how to fix this or at least explain to me why it-s completing the entire loop in 1 method call...

Thank you!

Comment: What is this called on? (How many times is this code called)

Comment: There is a timer, 2 seconds. It resets after the method is finished. The timer counts down using -= Time.deltaTime @Sayse

Comment: So how many times does it get called? The code itself doesn't look like the issue (to me), looks more like its called to many times, either all 4 objects are executing this code, or that timer is doing it too many times

Comment: @Sayse Well the code should loop forever, thats the whole idea atleast. I want to change the positions of the objects every 2 secs. They should be switching their positions forever.

Comment: Thats fine, and it should do, I'd imagine you need to look into the timer, I'm not too familiar with unity but Im sure it has its own game loop anyway and you should look into interacting with that rather than creating a separate timer. (Keep track of the last time since this method was called and only call if greater than 2 secs)

Comment: @Sayse The problem I see is that the Debug I get... TempPosition1 should only have the position of the Child(0) object, correct? Well the console throws out all 4 positions of the corners... WHY does it do that how?

Comment: Again speculation based on the fact I can't run this, but it isn't, if the code gets called 4 times then the position of the first object does in fact occupy all 4 positions at some time. You can prove this by logging all 4 positions each call

Comment: Can you post the class definition `Position Class`? I might be able to help you. If I am right. if `SwitchPositions` method is called once all 4 positions are being set to a same value I guess?

Comment: @CarbineCoder Actually all the setting and repositioning is done within the method SwitchPositions itself. I just dont understand why its getting called 4 times in 1 tick... It should do the thing and then wait till next call, but it just everything 4 times hence why I am getting 4 positions in Debug per 1 Temposition....

Comment: You say that tempPosition1 contains all 4 positions. How is a Position defined in unity? I would've assumed there is only one x/y/z value per position? Since your code looks alright, did you check if parent.transform.GetChild(0) actually returns the correct object with the correct position?

Comment: My mistake,  Transform.Position turn out to be of type  Vector3 which is a value type and that turns my answer into garbage. Only suggestion is to use a temp value to hold the positions before you swap them.

Comment: @H W tempPosition1 does not contain all 4 positions at once, since its not classified as a Vector array(In unity positions are defined by vectors). It can only contain 1 position at any given time. The fact that the Debug is giving me 4 different positions means that the code went through 4 times... I just want to know why it went through the whole 4 times? The debug should and everything else should only get executed once however it gets executed 4 times per call....

Comment: @NejcTrstenjak Check the call stack, may be you will know who calls this method

Comment: @CarbineCoder Right now I changed it so that I call the method via mouse input. Still gets executed 4 times per call...

Answer (score 1):

I am really not sure how your timer works or for that matter anything wrong with your code. But I have used the coroutine where after every two seconds the blocks get switched and it happens continuously. I think this should be somewhere close to what you need.

```
//Predefined positions where objects to place
public Transform[] Position;
//The objects that will will be swapped in coroutines
public Transform[] ObjectsToMove;
private int ObjectIndex = 0;
private bool startupdate = true;

void Update () {
    if(startupdate)
       StartCoroutine(SwitchBlocks());
}

IEnumerator SwitchBlocks() {
    startupdate = false;
    int tempIndex = ObjectIndex;
    for(int i = 0; i < ObjectsToMove.Length; i++) {
        tempIndex = ObjectIndex + i;
        if(tempIndex > ObjectsToMove.Length - 1)
            tempIndex -= ObjectsToMove.Length;
        ObjectsToMove[i].position = Position[tempIndex].position;
    }
    ObjectIndex++;
    if(ObjectIndex > ObjectsToMove.Length - 1) {
        ObjectIndex = 0;
    }
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(2.0f);
    startupdate = true;
    yield return null;
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Does not work... Does the exact same thing... Sorry, thanks though.

Comment: Would it be possible that its executing 4 times cause of 4 cores?

Comment: At this point I cannot say why your code is executing four times unless I see the entire code I cannot say and I dont think its getting executed because of four cores. Only two things come in my mind one is your timer function might not be correct so it gets executed like that or **SwitchPositions()** is being called from somewhere else also at the same time. If you are able to post the timer code from where this function is getting executed we might be able to solve it.